# Exclude in pmd not working

Tags: java, maven, pmd

I am unable to make the exclude work for the PMD. I need to exclude a generated-sources folder which is in the following directory structure:

> mainProject>subProject>target>generated-sources.

I have tried the rulesets as shown below:

```
<exclude-pattern>.*/generated-sources/*.java</exclude-pattern>
<exclude-pattern>.*/generated-sources/.*</exclude-pattern>
```

I have also went through their documentation & other stack-overflow links, but nothing seems to help. I tried with maven-pmd-plugin 3.1 & 3.6 versions.

Other options tried:

```
<!-- <excludeRoots>
    <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/**</excludeRoot>
</excludeRoots> -->
<!-- <excludes>
    <exclude>target/generated-sources/*.*</exclude>
</excludes> -->
<!-- <excludeRoots>
    <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/**</excludeRoot>
</excludeRoots> -->
<!-- <excludes>
    <exclude>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/*.java</exclude>
</excludes> -->
<!-- <excludeRoots>
    <excludeRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/**</excludeRoot>
</excludeRoots> -->
<!-- <excludes>
    <exclude>**/generated-sources/**/*.java</exclude>
</excludes> -->
<excludeRoots>
    <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources</excludeRoot>
</excludeRoots>
```

All these changes are done in the parent POM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your child pom, the excludeRoots needs to match the full folder name listed in compileSourceRoots for e.g.

[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [project/src/main/java, project/target/generated-sources/antlr4, project/target/generated-sources/annotations]

[DEBUG]   (f) excludeRoots = [project/target/generated-sources/antlr4, project/target/generated-sources/annotations]

The plugin definition in the child would look like

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeRoots>
                    <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/antlr4</excludeRoot>
                    <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/annotations</excludeRoot>
                </excludeRoots>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`excludeRoots`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#excludeRoots) parameter to do that. This enables to exclude source directories from the PMD report and subsequent checks. A sample configuration for the Maven `subProject` would be:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludeRoots>
      <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources</excludeRoot>
    </excludeRoots>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but even this did not help. I have updated my question with the things that I tried.

Comment: @Karthik did you put this in the `subProject` POM? Run Maven with `mvn clean install pmd:pmd pmd:check`.

Comment: No. I have this in the parent POM. Running that command did not help.

Comment: @Karthik That is expected then, as I said in the answer, you need to have that in `subProject`. If you have this in the parent project, then you must have `<excludeRoot>subProject/target/generated-sources</excludeRoot>` but it is not a good idea for the parent to depend on its modules.

Comment: I tried even this option. It did not help. I would like to add one more information here: the pmd-rules.xml is in the parent folder & is referred from there.